# Site Definition not available from Powershell

Tags: powershell, site-definition

Using SP 2013.

I have created a site definition in Visual Studio 2012.

Deployed that as a solution.

From the UI I can create a site and select the template I created.

However when I go into PowerShell and call `GetAvailableTemplates` on the root web, its not there?

For the site I created (from my site def) I go into PowerShell and get `SPWeb.WebTemplate` which is empty, `SPWeb.WebTemplateID` contains the ID, which in my case in 10001

If I use [SharePoint Manager](https://spm.codeplex.com/) that does actually show the name of the template.  Weird.

If I go into Page Layouts and Site Settings, set to only use my Site Template (which is obviously in the list) ... going back to PowerShell and calling `GetAvailableWebTemplates()` returns nothing...

I've read that it could be down to caching, but I don't think that affects Powershell ... i did an IIS reset anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after restarting SQL, IIS nothing seemed to help.  So I restarted the box and bingo.
Powershell is finding my template.

Love SharePoint!

Comment: Wonder if it was caching something (or lack thereof). Glad to hear it is working now for you though.

Comment: It was caching yes.  Although the restart was a temporary solution until i deployed the site def again.  I found this and wrote my own little PowerShell cmdlet - which has worked.  http://scle.me/17pKGmc

Answer (score 0):

Have specifically you tried the following:

```
get-spwebtemplate
```

That command should return back all of the globally installed site templates.

```
get-spwebtemplate "STS*"
```

That command returns specific details for the team site templates. And you can do other filters like that for the other "types" of templates.

Comment: Yep - tried that, should have said.  It's not listed in there either

Comment: I have just stuck a bit of C# in a page to output the templates ... SPWebTemplateCollection temps = SPContext.Current.Web.GetAvailableWebTemplates(1033);  and it is listed.  But not in PowerShell?

Comment: You don't have some sort of invoke command that is pointing to a different server / environment?

Comment: nope, certainly not.  i've done this a 100 times before in SP2010!  honest!